# Show form data in console on submit

Tags: javascript, html, console

Is it possible to show all the form data in console when the form is submitted and then the data is posted to the server as well?

Something like that?

```
<form action="http://whatever.com" method="POST" onSubmit="console.log(All Form Data)">
```

Thanks
Ahmar.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: write a function that would print all the form data in console, and call it from "onSubmit" in form tag.

Comment: It is possible using JavaScript or jQuery, but you should be careful what kind of data it is - posting passwords to the console is a massive security risk and if you're dealing with more sensitive stuff like bank details then posting the data to the console could get you prosecuted.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(function() {
  $('form').submit(function() {
    console.log('Input 1: '+$('input[name="input1"]').val() + ' Input 2: '+ $('input[name="input2"]').val()); // etc.
  });
});
```

or give Id's to inputs then

```
<form onSubmit="console.log('Input 1: '+document.getElementById('input1').value + ' Input 2: '+document.getElementById('input2').value)">
```